# If random variables converge to the same distribution for two different norming sequences, prove the norming sequences are asymptotically equivalent

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be deterministic positive increasing sequences such that $a_nX_n \stackrel{d}{\to}X$ and $b_nX_n \stackrel{d}{\to}X$, where $\{X_n\}$ and $X$ are random variables.

Prove or disprove $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n/b_n=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter-example $X_n=n^{-3},X=0, a_n =n^{2},b_n=n$. However, if $X$ is non-degenerate then the implication is true. This is "Convergence of Types Theorem".  See [Convergence of Types Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210948/convergence-of-types-theorem)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the reference! Proof seems highly non-trivial.